# How do I connect my external hard drive to Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

I'm going to be straight and to the point.

I have a WD My Book 25ee External Hard Drive.  It works fine on Windows 10 but does not work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Terminal commands I have tried and their outputs:

Input01: sudo lshw -C disk

Output01:

- description: SCSI Disk
- product: My Book 25 EE
- vendor: WD
- physical id: 0.0.0
- bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
- logical name: /dev/sda
- version: 4004
- serial: (not going to put that online)
- size: 3TB
- configuration:
  ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096

Input02: sudo fdisk -l

Output02: it does not show up in the list of drives.

I tried formatting the drive with Disks but I got "Error wiping device: failed to probe the device '/dev/sda' (udisks-error-quark, 0)" and I tried doing an ntfsfix command but that did not work either.  Additionally I have now tried shutting off the "fast startup" option from Windows 10 but I still have the same errors.

Every time I get a read/write error but I have found no solutions online.

Comment: Are you working on the terminal or on the GUI? The GUI should usually automount the drive. On the terminal, it ma be necessary to add an `fstab` entry. And of course, whis would address a partition (`/dev/sda1`), not the disk itself (`/dev/sda`).

Comment: @BurninLeo I am on the GUI and I have no idea what fstab is.  Is there a tutorial that you could link me too?

Comment: If drive was mounted with Windows 8 or 10, it sets the hibernation flag with fast start up, which then prevents Linux from opening read/write to prevent loss of data. You must turn off fast start up in Windows. You may be able to manually mount read/only. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: What partitions... ntfs? Windows data disk, or boot/primary disk? Can you run chkdsk on it in Windows? In Ubuntu, does `gparted` see the disk? If so, show me a screenshot. How is this disk showing as sda? Are there no other disks on this system? How are you connecting this disk? USB? SATA?

Comment: You need to enable USB 3 and/or USB charging in BIOS. I noteced that there was no sound from the HDD as it does with windows, so I figure out that was a POWER problem not a software one. EASY FIX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

The partitions are NTFS, the disk is shown as /dev/sda, the drive is an external drive connected by USB, and it cannot be seen in gParted.

I went into Windows 10 and reformatted the drive from exFAT to NTFS and then when I went back into Ubuntu it was magically working...I'm not sure why but it does.

I hope someone can explain this because I can't.

Comment: Microsoft exfat format was not recognized on Ubuntu 18.04. However, you can Firefox/Google search "exfat on Ubuntu 18.04" and get instructions for adding modules to read exfat files.